# I cannot reach the website www.github.com

Tags: networking, github

Whatever i tried to open github . com in my browser (tried with chrome and firefox), i failed to load web site

- i can reach every other web addresses except github . com
- i cannot take projec source codes from console via "git clone git:\..."
- i can ping the site

  `kursat@kursat:~$ ping github . com
  PING github.com (192.30.252.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from github.com (192.30.252.128): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=125 ms
  64 bytes from github.com (192.30.252.128): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=131 ms`
- when i check nslookup output was like this 

  `kursat@kursat:~$ nslookup github.com
  Server:     127.0.1.1
  Address:    127.0.1.1#53
  Non-authoritative answer:
  Name:   github.com
  Address: 192.30.252.129`
- when i try to make wget 

  `kursat@kursat:~$ wget github .com
  --2015-02-12 15:32:14--  http:// github .com/
  Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.252.128
  Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.252.128|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
  Location: https://github .com/ [following]
  --2015-02-12 15:32:14--  https:// github.com/
  Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.252.128|:443... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response...`
- when i make eth1 interface down and connect to the site via wlan0,i can connect the github.com

So i am really wondering what stops my eth1 to reach github.com ?

Comment: There too many variables here. Paste the output of `ifconfig`, `ip route` and `iptables -L` both while connected over LAN and over WiFi. Try those commands with sudo if there is no output.

Comment: ip route for eth1 as follows `kursat@kursat:~$  ip route
default via 192.168.3.1 dev eth1  proto static 
192.168.3.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.92  metric 1` for iptables there is no rule but accept everything

Comment: ip route for wlan : `default via 192.168.50.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.50.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.50.61  metric 9`

Comment: So there are two different networks here. I guess you can access some other HTTPS page but only github is the problem. Do you have any firewall rules on the gateway? You can also check dmesg and syslog or messages for some clues while on LAN trying to open github.com.